# Finding Stack Exchange sites that have a specific tag

Tags: support, tags, search

I want to ask a question about how to do something with DyNet. I am not sure what site is the best place for this question. A possible way to find out is to look for the site where the tag "dynet" exists (and, if there is more than one, find the site with the largest number of questions with this tag).

How can I find all the Stack Exchange sites that have a specific tag?

Comment: Maybe https://stackexchange.com/filters